# Prevent branch-indexing triggering builds when a manual build has already picked up changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have just setup a basic multibranch pipeline build job and have a feature branch with a jenkinsfile present which I am experimenting with.

I have the job configured to poll the scm every 5 mins and trigger a build if necessary.

I am finding however at times when I manually start a build for my branch after I have pushed up a tweak on my Jenkinsfile for example (as I don't want to wait for the next scm poll interval), the branch re-indexing activity can still trigger another build to be performed.

See the image below for what I mean, so here build 7 is one I kicked off manually on jenkins, so it picked up my commit, but then the branch indexing kicked off build 8 but there were no new changes for the branch.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Other than me being patient and waiting 5 mins of course!

Thanks

Comment: We recently experienced the same effect. I'm not sure, if this is a new bug, as IIRC this happened some weeks ago. Maybe check the issue tracker.

Comment: Do you still have this issue, or did you ever find the cause or a fix? I'm having the same issue on Jenkins LTS, and I've had it since I set the pipelines up.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this also. I tried playing with the polling settings in the Multibranch pipeline to see if this could fix it but that only led to no builds being spawned at all in response to SCM changes.

So this behaviour to which you refer was the best of a bad lot.

At time of writing, I think this behaviour is a bug with no current resolution.

Can't remember if I raised a ticket or not as I am in Azure DevOps world now.